# python : convert tuple to generator and free memory

Tags: python, tuples, generator

i have a python script that get huge data from database (millions) but it takes a lot of memory and slows the entire server

```
#open connection with database
#execute query in database
data = tuple(cursor.fetchall())
def dataGenerator(self, data):
    for i in data:
        yield i
del data
```

i tried to create a generator from the tuple and delete the data to free the memory but it wont work
i also tried using the cursor but i need to close the connection with the database
is there a way to do it please?

Comment: Iterate over cursor instead of doing `fetchall `

Comment: it keeps the connection open with the database and i need to close it

Comment: Then it won't work. When you do fetchall() you are loading whole data into memory.

Comment: Your question is illogical. If you don't want to keep the DB connection open and you don't want the results in memory, where do you expect the data to be stored for retrieval? Also, *why* do you need to close the connection? That's highly unusual as a requirement.

Comment: No, you can not do it! It is illogical! You can save `data` in some file but would it make the whole database usage obsolete? That is why you are using the database in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your requirements I think this solution will work best for you. FIrst fetch the data from DB:

```
import psycopg2
con = connect(user='root', host = 'localhost', database='pricing_db_new')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * from accounts')
```

Now I have the cursor we can write it to a temp file:

```
import json
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
tmp = NamedTemporaryFile()
_ = [tmp.write(json.dumps(c) + '\n') for c in cur.fetchall()]
```

This temp file exists as long as it is open and it gets deleted when you close it.

```
In [38]: tmp.name
Out[38]: '/tmp/tmpEQsoKt'
```

Now you can read your file line by line and yield result.

```
In [77]: tmp.seek(0) # seek to beginning to read again

In [78]: def read_file(file_obj):
    ...:     for row in file_obj.readlines(): # read line by line
    ...:         yield json.loads(row.strip())
    ...:

In [79]: gen = read_file(tmp)

In [80]: gen.next()
Out[80]:
[40507,
 None,
 3,
 107,
 None
]
```

Comment: Your last line about reading line by line is untrue. You've dumped the entire result as a single JSON list. You'll have to read the whole file. (The whole file may even be a single line.)

Comment: @jpmc26 thanks. Yes indeed! made the corrections to dump line by line.

Comment: If you're just going to store the list in the "don't care" `_` variable anyway, an actual loop is more appropriate than a comprehension.

Comment: @AmitTripathi It is certainly not more readable or idiomatic to store a list comprehension result in a throwaway variable. The entire point of a comprehension is to *create a list*, which is not needed here; so it is confusing. In this case, it's even counter-productive, causing the results to stay in memory (at least until the variable is reassigned, which doesn't happen automatically outside of IPython). I don't know what projects you're talking about, but either they had some out of the ordinary reason to do so or they're not writing Pythonic code.

Comment: `for c in cur.fetchall(): tmp.write(json.dumps(c) + '\n')` more clearly communicates your intentions (to process the results one item at a time, without storing them) and consumes less memory.